# Why does solution go to the right directions all the time with the gradient descent algorithm?

Tags: matlab, optimization, gradient-descent

I have a question with the classical gradient descent algorithm. Recently I want to implement a function fitting program provided the observed data as well as the parameters of the function is given. The method I have used is the gradient descent algorithm as the derivatives of the function are available. Suppose the function parameters are given, I can create the simulated data based on the function:

```
clean;
rng('default');
rng(54321);
low_value = 15;
high_value = 200;
dis_value  = (high_value-low_value)/2;
central_value = (low_value+high_value)/2;
x = 1:55;
central_pixel = (1+length(x))/2;
delta = 3;
len = length(x);
y_true = dis_value*erf((x-central_pixel)./delta)+central_value;
y = y_true + randn(1,len);
figure;plot(x,y,'b*');
hold on; plot(x,y_true,'r');
```

The figure below shows the simulated data (blur asterisk points )as well as the potential function (in red):
[image]
As you can see from the figure there are two parameters to estimate in this example, one is the center point position p and the other is the standard derivation delta, and the function is written as

[image]

where A and B can be regarded as known. Then if I want to use gradient descent algorithm, I should do two things: one is define the derivatives of the function for the two unknown parameters (p and delta) respectively, and the other is to invoke the gradient descent algorithm. However, what I have found confusing is that during the iterative procedure one of the estimated parameters (delta) does not go to the right direction all the time:

[image]

I do notice, however, that object function (the sum of the square distance between the fitting point and the estimated function) is always becoming smaller:
[image]

My question is then why the solutions do not always go to the right direction even though in the end they can reach the right place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gradient descent minimizer just follows the negative gradient of the function at its current location.  You (probably) gave the minimizer starting `(p,delta)` values where the negative gradient had delta increasing.  For different starting values, you will likely see different behavior.

One thought, though. Because `erfc( (x-p)/delta )` has the ratio of `p/delta`, your parameters are somewhat interdependent.  That is, for small values of `x`, or large values of `p/delta`, the ratio will dominate, and minimizers can get stuck in a cycle of continually increasing the magnitude of the numerator and the denominator.

Try using modified parameters: `erfc( x/delta - pdratio )`, and fitting to `delta` and `pdratio`.  You can then back out the original `p` parameter: `p = pdratio*delta`.